# Jetpack Compose Modifier.fillMaxWidth.align fails to compile

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Declaring a `Box` like this results in a compilation error

```
           Box(modifier = Modifier
                             .fillMaxWidth()
                             .align(Alignment.Center)) {
                            Text(text = "Hello")
                          }
```

import for `align` looks like this

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxScopeInstance.align
```

Error

```
Cannot access 'BoxScopeInstance': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout'
```

Compose Version = **1.1.1**

Kotlin Version = **1.6.10**

Android Studio Version = **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align` is supposed to be called from within the content of the `Box`

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
        text = "foobar"
    )
}
```

alternatively use `contentAlignment`

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(
        text = "foobar"
    )
}
```

Comment: Where can I find this in the official documentation?
"align is supposed to be called from within the content of the Box"

Comment: align is defined  in BoxScope so it can only be used in children of Box.

Answer (score 4):

The modifier.align() method can only be used in the `Box`, `Column`, `Row` layout scope.

For example, something like this.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
  Text("Hello")
  Text("World", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))
  Row(Modifier.align(Alignment.End)) {
     Icon(....)
  }
}
```

Using align in `Column` can only set Alignment whose property is `Alignment.Horizontal`, such as CenterHorizontally, Start, End.

Using align in `Row` can only set Alignment whose property is `Alignment.Vertical` such as CenterVertically Top, Bottom.

Use align in `Box` to set Alignment other than Alignment.Vertical and Alignment.Horizontal, such as TopStart, TopCenter, TopEnd, Center, BottomStart, BottomCenter, BottomEnd.